# Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.DLL' or one of its dependencies

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, chromium-embedded

I have a complex JavaScript algorithm that builds a page layout, takes its screenshot and e-mail it to the user. I can't execute it on the client side because of confidentiality of the algorithm and also the site can be used internationally and the HTML, CSS and JavaScript use some modern features that user browser may or may not support. So, what I am doing is executing the algorithm on Server side in a WinForms based browser. I started using CefSharp because it allows HTML5 features but I am getting following error whenever I run the application:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried adding the DLL as a reference but it's not working.

Comment: Do you have the required C++ libraries installed?

Comment: @Aishwarya Shiva are you able to resolve it?